# Firebase with Java / How can I get a value without an event listener?

Tags: java, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to get a String from the realtime database without any event listener. There won't be any event on the database at all so event listeners won't help me in this case. I looked for hundreds of tutorials and guides about getting data from the database but every single one of them used event listeners.

I used Firebase with Python before and there was a very simple way (`user = db.child("users").get()`) of doing what I am talking about. I couldn't find a similar thing for Java and would like to know if there is any way to do so. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: There is a [`get()` call](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#read_data_once) in Android too, but it'll still need a listener as the data is loaded asynchronously to prevent it from blocking the process. The only alternative without a listener would be to use the REST API.

Comment: Do you understand Kotlin? There is a solution in Kotlin in which you can read the data without the use of a listener. Please respond using @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo Sadly, I have no idea about Kotlin. I suppose I will stick with Postgresql instead of Firebase.